# IF it is not English alphabet then replace

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following dataset and I wish to replace those dataset that are not in English alphabet with something like"ABC"

```
Data

コハニー
Cat 
Blue
زبان
```

So my ideal output will be :

```
Data

ABC
Cat 
Blue
ABC
```

One option is using all the English alphabet like the following to identify the data that has no English alphabet inside.

```
df$Data <- ifelse(!grepl("A",df$Data ) .... |!grepl("Z",df$Data ) ,"ABC",grepl("A",df$Data ))
```

But is there any alternative option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grepl`

```
df$Data[!grepl('^[A-Za-z]+$', df$Data)] <- 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s <- c("コハニー", "Cat", "Blue", "زبان")
s[Encoding(s) == "UTF-8"] <- "ABC"
s
#[1] "ABC"  "Cat"  "Blue" "ABC"
```